# Finding the reason behind an RDP Certificate Change (man in the middle attack?)

Tags: certificates, man-in-the-middle, rdp

I've installed some new networking equipment: firewall, switches, vlans, etc. I won't mention the brand name here, because I don't want to cause them harm by my suspicions.

Right after doing this, I was able to RDP to a server inside my LAN without being prompted for a finger print change.

One day later, however, as I try to connect to that same server, it is now prompting me to accept a new certificate because the fingerprint has changed.

I have a suspicion that the new networking equipment is trying to gather the credentials of my servers by intercepting my RDP sessions in a manner that would be otherwise transparent except for the fact that I'm being  prompt to accept a changed certificate.

How can I confirm that this finger print change's source is something that has occurred on the server I'm connecting to, and not due to the new networking equipment trying to do a man in the middle attack to catalog credentials on my network (that it should not be curious about)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be narrowed down to a single device by first investigating the certificate on the server itself (access the console and RDP localhost to get the current certificate). Then, with a client computer, move farther away one network device at a time.

Once you've found the culprit, investigate the configuration: it could be a legitimate feature you have turned on by accident.

Comment: Or the server had a self-issued certificate which expired after 365 days, and the server generated a new one. (If OP's servers had CA-issued certificates, there would have been no "fingerprint prompt".)

Comment: True. This answer is more about methods for finding the reason, not guessing what it could be. :)

Comment: Some steps about finding the cert would have been nice in this answer, but I did find the cert and the new finger print did indeed match what was on the server. So no man in the middle here. Thank you.